# Distributing Mac App via Mac App Store and Own Website

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I want to distribute my Mac App on both Mac App Store and my own website. The Mac App Store app will be signed via the Mac App Distribution certificate from Apple and the Website version will be signed via the Developer ID Application certificate. The website version will be distributed as a simple MyAppName.zip file that lets the user unpack MyAppName.app to where ever the user wishes. My app is a document based app that creates documents with extension .mydoc

I have two options to implement such a scenario.

First, and my preferred method is to have same bundle identifier for both apps. If a user tries to install from MAS first and then website; Will both apps live on my Mac without any issues?  If a user installs the website version first, and then tries to install from MAS, how will MAS behave? How is it decided that which app will open my document by default?

Second, I use different bundle identifier for the apps on MAS and my website. Essentially they are different apps and I don't like this because it is confusing for a user because the apps look and behave exactly the same. In this case, how is it decided which one of the apps will open my document by default?

Answer (score 2):

*If a user tries to install from MAS first and then website; Will both apps live on my Mac without any issues?* **Answer**: YES

*If a user installs the website version first, and then tries to install from MAS, how will MAS behave?* **Answer:** MAS will ask user that there already exists a version and if it should be kept.

*How is it decided that which app will open my document by default?* **Answer:**
[Launch Services documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCTasks/LSCTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH203-SW4) says the the behavior is not determinate. So either one will open.

*Second, I use different bundle identifier for the apps on MAS and my website. Essentially they are different apps and I don't like this because it is confusing for a user because the apps look and behave exactly the same. In this case, how is it decided which one of the apps will open my document by default?* **Answer:**
[Launch Services documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABEJFCD) says the the behavior is not determinate. So either one will open.